# Configuring QGIS Web Server and Web Client on ubuntu?

Tags: qgis, ubuntu, qgis-server, qgis-web-client

I'm trying to properly install and config the web server and web client on an ubuntu machine (14.04)
For now, I'm just testing it, to present later to my boss.

I followed these links:
qgis-web-server-tutorial-wiki, and anitagreser-step-by-step-on-ubuntu (I can't post more than 2 links, hehe)

so... i'm at this point

When i try the GetCapabilities, this happens:
[image: print-screen-1]
(Is this the page I should see?)

When I try the /ip-local-machine/qgis-web-client/site, i get this:
[image: print-screen 2]

And when i hit the naturalearth link, I get stuck on a "loading map" page... forever....

Can anyone help me?

Comment: The response to a GetCapabilities request is an XML response like you seem to have in your first image.  It should list all the layers of data available in your service.

Comment: Well, that sounds good! I didn't create any projects yet... I thought that, if I can't even show the examples, I wouldn't bother on creating a new project.

Comment: The GetCapabilities tells a GIS client (like QGIS) what your service can do and with what data.  If you haven't added any data (even if it is example data) then your service won't be able to show anything.  I don't know anything about the QGIS Web Server config, but if your GetCapabilities doesn't show any layers then that should help you debug the issue.

Comment: I just have the example data. When I try to show the examples, my web client gets stuck in a "Loading Map" page

Comment: What happens if you try and load your service into QGIS using the Add WMS/WMTS option ~ you provide your URL up to and including the question mark but none of the parameters. Can you load a layer or do you get an error?

Comment: Could you open up the console with (F12 in firefox) and tell us what errors you get. Second thing you should check is if you get any erros from apache server and also paste it.